# Zurb Foundation: Does the basic grid work without javascript?

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

If i only want to use the basic responsive grid functionality of Zurb's Foundation (no plugins), do i need to include foundation.js and initialize it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need JS. And you can check it with the [docs.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/) Modules that require js has js label in the menu.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how i did not see those labels. So the only thing that depends on javascript regarding "Structure" is "Interchange".

Comment: @Christoph yes "Interchange" won't work without js. In the example page they have additional <noscript> tag with the default image.

Comment: Are there any docs about how to use foundation without JS? I searched the link you provided, but it doesn't really mention it clearly how to do this.